# I get a error from Python 3.6.2: TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not bytes

Tags: python

Ive searched on StackOverflow, but none of the  mentioned tricks worked.
Here follows my code.

```
    from socket import *
import time

address= ( '10.1.15.243', '5000') #Server data
client_socket =socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM) #Socket klaarzetten
client_socket.settimeout(1) #Response time

while(1):

    data = "Positie" #Data request = Positie

    client_socket.sendto( (b'10.1.15.243'), (b'5000') ) #Data aanvragen

    try:

        rec_data, addr = client_socket.recvfrom(2048) #Read response from arduino
        temp = float(rec_data) #Convert string rec_data naar float temp
        with open('resultaten.txt', 'w') as f: #Data in TXT opslaan
            print('Positie:', filename, file=f) #Data confirmen
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: `(b'5000')` isn't a tuple; it's just `b'5000'` in expression-grouping parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) says:

> A pair (host, port) is used for the AF_INET address family, where host is a string representing either a hostname in Internet domain notation like 'daring.cwi.nl' or an IPv4 address like '100.50.200.5', and port is an integer.

`sendto` expects the message & the address so 2 parameters. You're passing this:

```
client_socket.sendto( (b'10.1.15.243'), (b'5000') )
```

so viewed from `sendto`, the message is `b'10.1.15.243'` and the address is `b'5000'`. `b"5000"` is a bytes object, which explains the error message. The parentheses here have no effect (and even if they *did* define tuples, that would still be incorrect). Moreover, you also forgot to pass your payload...

As `address` is a proper address tuple (`('10.1.15.243','5000')`), just do:

```
data = b"Positie"  # needs to be bytes object
client_socket.sendto(data, address)
```

(address is properly defined above)